# Why does parameterizing a curve with its length yield $|g(T,T)|=1$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Let $l(t)=\int^t_{t_0}|T|(t')dt'$, where $T$ is a tangent vector to some curve $C(t)$.

Why does setting this function as a parameterization of the curve $C$, hence letting $l(t)=\psi C(t)$, imply $|T|^2=|g(T,T)|=1$? I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @mmeent in expanding $dl=\sqrt{|g(T,T)|}$ with the parameterisation I just get $dl=dl$, I dont know what to make of this.

Comment: Why is this here in physics.SE?

Comment: @MBN This is math used in general relativity

Comment: @YG It is still a math only question. No part of it is about any physics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of letting $l(t)=\psi C(t)$, what was meant was having $l(t)=t$. Then the result follows simply from $t=\int^t_{t_0}1dt'+t_0$.